# Software to generate compound library

Tags: software-recommendations, qsar

I'm trying to perform a QSPR research and for it I need to generate a library of compounds.
Now I'm using a plugin for MarvinSkectch for enumerating Markush structures but it doesn't work properly (maybe I misuse it). So I'm looking for a free/trial software that allows to generate compound library based on general structure.

Comment: Do you need to generate your own library? The [ZINC](https://zinc.docking.org/) library have millions of structures to download.

Comment: I plan to use to predict physico-chemical properties of particular classes of compounds, so I need to generate library from block that I will define myself.

Comment: I already used [LigBuilder](http://www.pkumdl.cn:8080/ligbuilder3/), a *de novo* drug design software but I don't know if it is capable to generate molecules alone (it is designed to generate molecules interacting with a given target).

Comment: Looks like it's targeted to drug design only, but I need to generate structures for completely different purpose.

Comment: Take a look at this software: _VLG or Virtual Library Generator is a tool for generating compounds by adding substituents to a scaffold_, from [here](http://www.biochem-caflisch.uzh.ch/download), I think it can do what you need.

Comment: Did Camps' suggestion of VLG help at all?

Comment: I've tried every software mentioned and also found one myself. Its named SmiLib and I like the most. But MarvinSketch now woks on my PC, so I use it.

Comment: The [Materials Project](https://materialsproject.org/) is also a great resource.

Comment: @romaichenko we have to clear up the unanswered queue, which now has over 110 questions. Maybe you could write an answer to your own question, about how to get MarvinSketch working for this? It seems  like a valid answer to your software-recommendations question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon the request I'm sharing the solution I came to.

So, as I mentioned in the comments, I've finally make MarvinSkectch Markush enumeration feature to work properly. I don't really know what I've been doing wrong, as it just started working as intended. ChemAxon have a small tutorial on this feature. [ChemAxon tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8xDe1P_dgQ)